# Applescript remove folder from directory with special characters and spaces

Tags: macos, shell, applescript

I have run into some installation problems with the new Sierra update.
I want to run a script that checks the version number and deletes a certain .mpkg file based on the version number because I am having a lot of customers running the wrong installation which is causing a lot of issues.  I have tried multiple versions of this code and nothing seems to be working.  My result in Applescript console is: "".
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
tell application "Finder"

    set os_version to do shell script "sw_vers -productVersion"

    if ((os_version as string) is equal to "10.12") then

    do shell script (" rm  -rf \"Step 1 Installer.mpkg\" ")

else

    do shell script (" rm -rf  \"Step 1 Installer (SIERRA ONLY).mpkg\" ")

end if
end tell
```

Comment: Your first test is probably never true because the version is never "10.12". I guess version is "10.12.xx". Instead of 'is equal', you should use 'contains'. then script will found version 10.12 for any values of "xx".

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  I took your advice and still got the same result.

Comment: in 'rm' instruction, the -f option is set to not display any message, even if the files to be deleted do not exist. So you get no error if the file does not exist. I would be surprised that file "step 1 Installer.mpkg" exists in the root of your hard drive ..that's probably the reason.

Comment: I have my file located in a place where the installers exist.  They are in a directory together.  When I run the script.  step 1 installer.mpkg is not removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you run the `rm` command, you don't specify the directory the .mpkg file is in. It *does not* automatically look in the same directory the script is in. Instead, it looks in whatever the script's working directory is, which seems to be `/` (i.e. the top level of the system volume). You can use `path to me` to get the script's path, then you need to convert that to a POSIX path in quoted form to use in the shell, then get the parent directory name... Here's what I came up with:

```
set scriptPath to POSIX path of ((path to me) as string)
do shell script "rm -Rf \"$(dirname " & (quoted form of POSIX path of (scriptFile)) & ")/Step 1 Installer.mpkg\""
```

(and a similar variant for the other installer)

**Warning: *I have not fully tested this**, and it contains an `rm -Rf` command. Thus, if something goes wrong it could go very very wrong. Test well, on a system that you don't care about.